# How to rewrite URL to index.php with a query even if a file/directory/location exists?

Tags: php, apache, url, url-rewriting

I'm trying to rewrite everything from my website to a file index.php with a query parameter that contains requested path, but when I just simply do `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [L]` my index.php file displays that url contains index.php...
Simply, I want to type localhost/123 or localhost/123.php and always get the path part in my url parameter.

`print_r($_GET['url'])` outputs `Array ( [url] => index.php )` no matter what path part is.

Sorry for my English, hope u'll understand what I mean :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a different flag in your RewriteRule

Instead of [L]

> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [L]

Try something like [QSA]

> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA]

For a list and information of the different types of flags, check out Apache's Documentation

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html